# what is the use of durability in quartz xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

Here a property mention that durability=true.

```
<bean name="complexJobDetail"   class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.websystique.spring.quartz.ScheduledJob" />
    <property name="jobDataMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="anotherBean" value-ref="anotherBean1" />
            <entry key="myBean" value-ref="myBean" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>
```

could you please explain what is the use of durability=true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/JobDetailFactoryBean.html):

> Specify the job's durability, i.e. whether it should remain stored in
>   the job store even if no triggers point to it anymore.